# Google App Engine: Ignore URL Case when finding appropriate Handler

Tags: google-app-engine

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                 [('/', DefaultPage),
                                  ('/ClearDataPage', ClearDataPage),
                                  ('/DeleteTweets', DeleteTweets),
                                  ('/DeleteLinks', DeleteLinks),
                                  ('/awesome', Awesome),
                                  ('/RunScriptPage', RunScriptPage)],
                                 debug=True)
```

In this scenario, how do I make any variations of "Awesome" or for that matter any url case insensitive?

such that Awesome will always be directed to localhost:8080/awesome ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such somewhat advanced dispatching needs, don't use the *extremely* lightweight `webapp` framework -- use any of the richer ones, such as [web.py](http://webpy.org/), that App Engine also supports; there, you can dispatch based on regular expressions, not just strings, so you can in particular use a case-insensitive regular expression pattern.

For example, `'(?i)awesome'` is the pattern for a regular expression that matches `'awesome'` in a case-insensitive manner, as you desire.

Comment: Hold it right there! Webapp also supports dispatching on regular expressions! The regex you suggest for web.py will work perfectly on webapp.

Answer (score 4):

You may use regular expressions in this case. [Wikipedia: Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Some app engine specific examples can be found in the [app engine docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html).